# Accessing DOM of external webpage using $.get

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert specific elements of a webpage into another webpage. I'm using $.get to pull in the HTML. My problems begin when I try to access any of the DOM elements. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

```js
    <script>
    $.get("test.html", function(data){
      $( "body" )
        .append( "Name: " + data.getElementsByName('p')   );
    },"html");
    </script>
```

Comment: You should either prepare test.html containing HTML that is ready to be inserted directly without manipulation with `$.html()` or use JSON to return an object upon AJAX request to manipulate your current DOM.

Comment: If I reference "data", it prints everything with <body>, how do I just access a single element i.e. <p>?

Comment: `$.parseHTML()` might be the function you want here. You can parse HTML string into DOM nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a string. You can wrap that string in `$()` and manipulate the resultant elements

```
$( "body" )
        .append( "Name:"  )
        .append($(data).find('p))
```

Assumes that the `<p>` are not at root level of test.html. If they are then use `filter()` instead of `find()`

Comment: This worked for me. I ended up using <pre>filter()</pre> instead of <pre>find</pre>